# Elasticsearch 6: Extra information in aggregation results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm making query like

```
 aggs: {
         
            all_devices_types: {
              nested: {
                path: 'devices'
              },
              aggs: {
                devices_device_name: {
                  terms: {
                    field: 'devices.brand_name'
                  }
                },
                devices_brand_name: {
                  terms: {
                    field: 'devices.device_name'
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

All devices have brand so one record look like this

```
{
"device_name": "R Max",
"device_id": "767",
"brand_name": "Addas",
"brand_id": "726"
}
```

After i make this aggregation query i get results eg.

```
"devices_device_name": {
"doc_count_error_upper_bound": 2,
"sum_other_doc_count": 81,
"buckets": [
{
"key": "R max ",
"doc_count": 1406
}
] 
}
```

I need in this aggregation also have vlue "brand_name" so results should looks like

"devices_device_name": {
"doc_count_error_upper_bound": 2,
"sum_other_doc_count": 81,
"buckets": [
{
"brand_name": "Addidass"
"key": "R max ",
"doc_count": 1406
}
]
}

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't-ish -- at least not without resorting to [scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62330687/8160318).

What you **can** do is an aggregation within an aggregation:

```
GET brands/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "all_devices_types": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "devices"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_device_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "devices.device_name"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "by_brand_name": {
              "terms": {
                 "field": "devices.brand_name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which results in counts of `brand_name` within a given `device_name`

```
[
  {
    "key":"R Max",
    "doc_count":1,
    "by_brand_name":{
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
      "sum_other_doc_count":0,
      "buckets":[
        {
          "key":"Addas",
          "doc_count":1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```